# How to return result from SQL Query when any changes in status column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still new in writing complex query. It will be helpful if anyone could give me any solution to this.

I have set of records, which I would it to return the Date and Status when the status changes.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLUga.png]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you @sqlzim, I will learn about it, this is my first time in here

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012+, using [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

```
select s.[date],s.[status]
from (
  select [date],[status],lag([status]) over (order by date) as prev_status
  from tbl
  ) s
where s.[status]<>s.prev_status 
  or s.prev_status is null
```

---

Prior to SQL Server 2012+, using [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select t.[date],t.[status]
from tbl as t
outer apply (
  select top 1 i.[status] as prev_status
  from tbl as i
  where i.[date] < t.[date]
  order by i.[date] desc
  ) s
where t.[status]<>s.prev_status 
  or s.prev_status is null
```

Comment: Could you explain lag function

Comment: @Khalil As per the documentation linked in my answer, `lag()`: [Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

Comment: I don't really get it if I want to use the LAG. and also, will it be possible if I want to add 'order by [Time] desc'?

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal Yes, it would work with `order by [Time] desc` if you have separate columns for `date` and `time`, then you could use both ascending or descending, such as `(order by [date] desc, [time] desc)` or `(order by [date], [time])`.

Comment: Hey Thank you, that will work! I will go take a look on lag()